# How to request microphone access again after user disallowed previously?

Tags: ios, permissions, ios7, recording

1. I want to record.
2. User disallowed.
3. I want to record again.
4. I call requestRecordPermission:
5. It simply returns granted=NO (without prompting for permission)

Can I prompt the permission Alert to user somehow?
Or I should go with some custom message like "Grant access in Settings/Privacy"?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this - it works in the same way as the prompt for location services. The only thing you can do is let the user know via an alert etc that your app requires the mic to work properly.